# 403 Forbidden Error Page for keyboard symbol

Tags: wordpress

I get a

> 403 Forbidden Error Page

every time I add an Apostrophe `'` in the search form, all other symbols seem to work well I'm not sure why I get a error in the search form when I search for an apostrophe. Here's my search form code if that has anything to do with it..

```
<form method="get" 
   class="search-form" 
   id="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<input type="search" 
   class="search-field" 
   placeholder="<?php _e('Search form', 'fukasawa'); ?>" name="s" id="s" /> 
<a id="searchsubmit" 
   class="search-button" 
   onclick="document.getElementById('search-form').submit(); return false;">
   <div class="genericon genericon-search"></div></a>
```

Comment: i think it has to do with bulletproof plugin when i empty out the .htaaccess it works, any way i can get it working with bulletproof plugin.

Comment: got the answer here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/403-forbidden-error-24?replies=4